# How can i delete posts after 24 hours since they were posted?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this lines in my code :

```
PostedId.Add(responsePost);
PostedId.Add(DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString());
```

PostedId is List
I add to it the id of posted Post and also add the Date of the post.

Then i have this button click event that delete the posts according to each pos id:

```
private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { 
            var responsePost = "";
            try
            {
                var objFacebookClient = new FacebookClient(AccessPageToken);
                for (int i = 0; i < PostedId.Count; i++)
                {
                    char[] array = PostedId[i].Where(c => Char.IsDigit(c) || c == '_').ToArray();
                    string s1 = new string(array);
                    objFacebookClient.Delete(s1);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                responsePost = "Facebook Posting Error Message: " + ex.Message;
            }
        }
```

Instead button click event i will move later the code to a timer event.
What i want to add to code is check that if the id date it was sent passed 24 hours(a day) then delete it.

This is example of how the PostedId List look like:

```
index 0: {"id":"344087212396598_344923118979674"}
index 1: Wednesday, February 19, 2014
index 2: {"id":"344087212396598_344923125646340"}
index 3: Wednesday, February 19, 2014
```

Index 1 belong show the date index 0 id was sent.
Index 3 is the date of when index 2 was sent.

I want to check that if the date in index 1 passed 24 hours delete index 0 and then delete it self index 1.

Then the same for index 3 and 2. When the date in index 3 passed 24 hours first delete index 2 then delete index 3.

And so on for all the index in PostedId List.

How can i add this check in my button7 click event so when i click like now it wont delete all the posts automatic but only those who passed 24 hours ?

EDIT**

This is what i did now:

At the top of the form i added:

```
private List<DateTime> dt = new List<DateTime>();
```

Then added :

```
PostedId.Add(responsePost);
dt.Add(DateTime.Now);
```

Then i check the dates:

```
private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TimeSpan span = new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0, 0);
            var responsePost = "";
            try
            {
                var objFacebookClient = new FacebookClient(AccessPageToken);
                for (int i = 0; i < PostedId.Count; i++)
                {
                    char[] array = PostedId[i].Where(c => Char.IsDigit(c) || c == '_').ToArray();
                    string s1 = new string(array);
                    if (dt[i] <= DateTime.Now.Subtract(span))
                    {
                        objFacebookClient.Delete(s1);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                responsePost = "Facebook Posting Error Message: " + ex.Message;
            }
        }
```

Is that right ? I mean doing if (dt[i] <= DateTime.Now.Subtract(span)) is the right comparison ?

I used a breakpoint:

Now i = 0 so dt index 0 is: {2/19/2014 7:56:07 PM}
And span is: 1, 0, 0, 0
And DateTime.Now in the DateTime.Now.Subtract is: {2/19/2014 7:59:08 PM}

So when it will delete it ? After 24 hours ? I did it right ?

Comment: Edited my question now with what i did . Is that right ?

Comment: @user3200169 Why do you say 'my question'?. AFAIK this question is from user2704319 which is clearly a different identitiy. Can you clarify this?

Comment: Yes i asked the question from my wife laptop she have a different account in StackOverFlow. Sorry.

Comment: Have a look at [in-private browsing](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/what-is-inprivate-browsing#1TC=windows-7)

Answer (score 1):

you could use something along the lines of

```
TimeSpan span = new Timespan(1,0,0,0) //this sets the span to one day
```

then do a comparison

```
if(message.date =< DateTime.Now.Subtract(span))
{
        //do stuff
}

else
{
        // do something else
}
```

Comment: Edited my question now with what i did . Is that right ?

Comment: Yes that looks correct, I will run a test when i get into the office and confirm for you